# Need assistance in tracing this function that has to do with python iterators and generators

Tags: python-3.x

```
def skip_last(iterator):

    prev = next(iterator)
    for item in iterator:
        yield prev
        prev = item

for row in skip_last(CSV_reader):
    print(row)
print("Completed")
```

I know that the function is supposed to skip the last line of a file read into a CSV reader using the python csv module. Just having trouble visualizing the flow. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Let's assume we have a text file that contains the following sample data, and we want to call the skip_last function to print all rows in the file to standard output with the FOOTER record removed.

```
ABC 123
DEF 456
GHI 789
FOOTER
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `prev = next(iterator)` reads in the first element of the iterator.

The loop `for item in iterator:` goes through the remaining items one by one. But notice that it doesn't yield `item`. It yields `prev`, which lags one element behind `item`.

The assignment `prev = item` maintains the lag. When the iterator is done (iterated through the *last* line), your generator is one element behind (yielded the *second to last* line).

You can make a table of `prev`, and `item` when the `yield` happens:

```
 prev       item
-------------------
ABC 123    DEF 456
DEF 456    GHI 789
GHI 789    FOOTER
```

Basically, when `item` gets to the last element, `FOOTER`, iteration stops, but by that point `prev` has yielded everything up to the second to last element, `GHI 789`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Makes sense now.